# the signing certificate and private key do not match or do not contain valid information

Tags: openssl, installation, setup-deployment, sign, signtool

i am working a setup project and i want to sign my "setup.exe" file.

For this issue, i have;

- A "setup.exe" file
- A "aaa.pfx" file (Also i am using this pfx file as my site ssl certificate.)

Firstly,

i converted pfx file to crt and pvk above command.

- Export private key: `openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -nocerts -out key.pvk`
- Export certificate: `openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.crt`

And I am using windows signwizard tool for signing,

Steps:

- I selected my "setup.exe" file
- I selected my "cert.crt"
- I selected "key.pvk" And this get an error like picture;

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
1.
openssl sha256 -out digest.txt setup.exe
2.
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.pvk -out signed_setup.exe digest.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you use the same `PFX` (which is a `PKCS#12` equivalent) for your SSL site certificate.

That is the problem: you cannot use such a certificate which type is `TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication` to sign code like a `setup.exe`

When reading the exported certificate with

```
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text
```

You have to look for `X509v3 Extended Key Usage:` line.

To sign code, it must be: `Code Signing, Microsoft Commercial Code Signing`, it is a different service and a different price for certificate authority providers !